# How to flush Redis keyspace of expired keys?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

Backstory: The keyspace of the Redis database in question reports a large amount of expired keys and memory usage is maxed out. The application using this database is experiencing (rare) intermittent timeouts and I thought (in my limited knowledge) perhaps it is because Redis is having to eject expired keys each time a new key is created.

So to my question: **how do I tell Redis to remove all the expired keys?**

Secondarily -- is it possible to access/see expired keys with redis-cli?

Here's a slice of the `INFO` I'm looking at:

```
maxmemory_policy:allkeys-lru
expired_keys:24326586
evicted_keys:134022997
keyspace_hits:2684031719
keyspace_misses:186380210
slave_expires_tracked_keys:0
active_defrag_key_hits:0
active_defrag_key_misses:0
db2:keys=12994468,expires=3193,avg_ttl=1891176
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for myself, posterity, and any other Redis newbies out there. I was looking at the wrong "database". I was under the *WRONG* impression that Redis only had single table but looking at my question you see "db2". I searched into that and found that Redis can have up to 16 databases identified by a zero-based index. In this case:

```
SELECT 2
```

That selects "db2" and now doing a `DBSIZE` gives a more accurate output.

Oye -- so the problem is that the keys are *still there!* Otherwise when Redis expires a key it *deletes it*.

Whoops! I'm leaving my question because someone else might think to ask the same thing and be on the wrong route.